# REPLACE with JOIN - SQL

Tags: sql

I need help to understand what I did wrong ... I'm a beginner so excuse me the simple question!

I have two tables in which I want to do a JOIN where, in one of the columns I had to use REPLACE to remove the text 'RIxRE' that does not interest me.

In table 1, this is the original text of the column id_notification: RIxRE-1787216-BSB and this is the text that returns when using REPLACE: 1787216-BSB
In column 2, this is the text that exists: 1787216-BSB

However, I get the following error:

> # 1054 - Unknown column 'a.id_not' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(a.id_notificacao,'RIxRE','') AS id_not
FROM robo_qualinet_cadastro_remedy a
JOIN (SELECT * FROM painel_monitoracao) b ON a.id_not = b.id_notificacao
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a column alias again in the `FROM` clause or the `WHERE` clause after the `SELECT` (and possibly not other clauses as well, depending on the database).

So, repeat the expression:

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(a.id_notificacao, 'RIxRE', '') AS id_not
FROM robo_qualinet_cadastro_remedy rqcr JOIN 
     painel_monitoracao pm
     ON REPLACE(rqcr.id_notificacao, 'RIxRE', '') = pm.id_notificacao;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases the mean something, such as abbreviations for the able names.
- The subquery is not necessary in the `FROM` clause.
- I suspect that you have a problem with your data model if you need a `REPLACE()` for the `JOIN` condition, but that is a different issue from this question.